# Python generics: Reuse class generic type

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing

What's the correct way to "reuse" or refer to the generic type a class was instantiated with, while instantiating another generic class?

Consider the example below. Class A works as I expect when I have a concrete generic type (e.g. 'str' in the main method) - but how can I reuse that in B::get_t, such that A is instantiated with the generic type B was instantiated with? I can make it work in a way that feels hacky, but gets a mypy error.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T')


class A(Generic[T]):
    def get_t(self) -> T:
        t = self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]
        obj = t.__new__(t)
        obj.__init__()
        return obj


class B(Generic[T]):
    def get_t(self) -> T:
        # This works, but mypy gives "Variable "t" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]mypy(error)"
        t = self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]
        a = A[t]()

        # This fails (object.__new__(X): X is not a type object (TypeVar))
        # I'm guessing it fails since T is just the variable above.
        a = A[T]()
        return a.get_t()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A[str]()
    obj: str = a.get_t()

    b = B[str]()
    obj: str = b.get_t()
```

Comment: `a = typing.cast('A[T]', A())` or `a: 'A[T]' = A()`. Also `a: A[T] = A()` if you're using annotations future-import. Or do you use custom `__class_getitem__` (or metaclass `__getitem__`) and really need the typevar passed?

Comment: @SUTerliakov I need `A` to know what `T` maps to. I know I can access it using `t = self.__orig_class__.__args__[0]` from within `A` (and `B` in my example).

Comment: This seems to boil down to the rule that does not allow the use of (regular) variables in type annotations, i.e. `t = ...`, then `A[t]`, even if you do `assert isinstance(t, type)` in between. This works at runtime, but is not accepted by the static type checker. Interesting. I see no way around this at the moment other than adding `# type: ignore[valid-type]` next to the `a = A[t]()` line.